# gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1 React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gradle

I'm just trying to run a simple and empty react native project in android emulator but I'm getting this error anyone have any ideas?

error:

> Error: C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\ReactNative\MemorizingApp\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
> Error: C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\ReactNative\MemorizingApp\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
> at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\ReactNative\MemorizingApp\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
> at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\ReactNative\MemorizingApp\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
> at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
> ...
> at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\ReactNative\MemorizingApp\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
> at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\ReactNative\MemorizingApp\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
> at Object.assembleAsync (C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\ReactNative\MemorizingApp\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
> at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\ReactNative\MemorizingApp\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:31:24)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I did not have Gradle installed on my machine.

1. check if you have Gradle installed `gradle -v`
2. if not, install it with Chocolatey `choco install gradle` (there are other ways to install it)
3. If yes, run `gradle --stop` to ensure that no gradle daemon is running
4. Remove build folder
5. refresh terminal by running `refreshenv` in it